# how to send email in Iphone code

Tags: ios4, message, sendmail

Hi I have built a view controller with EmailID textField and a comments textView and also a send button. I need to send the email from here and not use the MFMailComposeViewController.

my question is how to just create a mail object and send it thru code without apple's view controller?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can try and use this SMTP SDK for the iPhone - http://code.google.com/p/skpsmtpmessage/